# AWS SES Use user email address in from field

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is it possible to use a user/customer email address in the from field when the user is filling out a contact form?

I know that the sending of emails requires a confirmed email/domain and I have done some googling and rtf-ing, but I couldn't really find a solid answer.

I have tried php mail function and that works okay, but when the ELB kicks in, there's some conflicts with deliverability.

Comment: We don't do "does anyone know of a good x..." questions, here.  Have you considered trying to set the `Reply-to:` address, instead of `From:`?

Comment: I have set the reply to, However client wantsusers email to be in the from.

Comment: I suggest that you convince the client otherwise. [DMARC policy](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/SLN24016.html) will also be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can **ONLY** use a confirmed email address (or ANYTHING@aConfirmedDomain) in the From: field of SES.  Failure to use a confirmed email will stop the email from going out of SES.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html

So to answer your question specifically.  If a random person fills out a form on your website and you use that information to send an email you **cannot** set the FROM address as somerandomuser@somerandomdomain.com .    SES will decline the mail.

If you want to send an email from a contact us FORM, I suggest you add a confirmed email address like 'noreply@mydomain.com' to your SES settings and then use 'noreply@mydomain.com' as the FROM address of your contact form.